# Evaluating coefficients of Eisenstein series of weight one for $\Gamma(N)$ by polynomials through examining basis

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms

I am interested in the claim from F.Diamond & J.Shurman, "A First Course in Modular Forms" that if $f$ is a modular form w.r.t. a congruence subgroup, then

> in the Fourier expansion $f(τ) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nq_N^n$, the coefficients satisfy the condition $|a_n|≤Cn^r$ for some positive constants $C$ and $r$.

For cusp forms, we can utilize Petersson inner product to show this. On the other hand, for Eisenstein series, the authors prove this claim first for Eisenstein series for $\Gamma_1(N)$. Because they have a explicit basis of the space of such series, they directly confirm that members of the basis satisfy the estimate in the claim to get the desired result. Then, for Eisenstein series for a general congruence subgroup, or equivalently for those for $\Gamma(N)$, they only say that the evaluation for the series for $\Gamma_1(N)$ readily extends to the general case.

Luckily, a basis of the space of Eisenstein series for $\Gamma(N)$ is on the book, for weight more than one. For weight one, the authors construct some series for $\Gamma(N)$, i.e. $g_1^{v}(\tau) = \frac{1}{N}Z_{\Lambda} \left(\frac{c\tau + d}{N}\right)-\frac{c\eta _1(\Lambda) + d\eta _2(\Lambda)}{N^2}$, where $Z_{\Lambda}$ is Weierstress Zeta Function w.r.t. the lattice $\Lambda$ generated by $1$ and $\tau$, $v = (c,d)\in (\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z)^2$ is of order $N$, and $\eta _1$, etc is the constants appearing in Legendre relation. However, they do not mention if they make up a basis of the space. (See http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/MF/errata4.pdf for those who have the book.)

My question is:

> is there any way to easily show that the series above span the space of Eisenstein series for $\Gamma(N)$ of weight one? Or, is there another way to show the first polynomial evaluation?

P.S.

I am also aware of https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0065293, which include an article by J-P.Serre, and H.M. Stark determining the basis of the space of weight one modular forms for $\Gamma(N)$. So, I would read it if there are no other ways.

Comment: Congruence subgroup means that the Eisenstein series are (by a dimension argument ?) $\sum_{c,d,P(c,d)} \frac1{(cz+d)^k}$ for $P$ some system of congruence equations which means it is a sum of shifts and scales of those of $SL_2(Z)$ (or $\Gamma_1(4)$ for the odd weights).

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice it!

Comment: For the even weights $\ge 4$ it is easier : those sums give a $\# cusp$-dimensional space of Eisenstein series, and the map sending a modular form to its value at the cusps has kernel the cusp forms, thus the Eisenstein subspace can't be more than $\# cusp$-dimensional. The difficulty is for the odd weights and weight $2$.

Comment: @reuns I wonder how you show that the Eisenstein series are of that form. Especially considering weight one, I am unsure of whether your series converges. Could you tell me more about it?

Comment: For $k$ odd or $2$ the values at the cusps must sum to $0$ because otherwise $\sum_{\gamma \in SL_2(Z)/\Gamma(n)} f|_k \gamma(z)$ would be a non-zero weight $k$ Eisenstein series for $SL_2(Z)$. For the odd weights there are more symmetries imposed.

Comment: I wonder if you mean that every modular form is a cusp form. Could you correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: reuns means the dimension of Eisenstein series is given by the number of cusps.  Eisenstein series are not cusp forms of course.

Comment: I noticed that not on the book is the proof that the construction on the book of Eisenstein series of weight 2 for $\Gamma(N)$ give a basis of the space of such series. Therefore, I feel like admitting the same thing for weight 1. Thank you for your comments and attention, and I welcome any information.